# Add a secondary admin to SP sites including OneDrive sites, change sites locale and remove the secondary admin account - PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, locale, sharepoint-online, onedrive

Good morning all.

I have a dilemma - our SP tenant has been set with UK region, but with US locale. and this causes problems with American date formats etc.

I have run the following PS script (thanks Michael Han_MSFT) to change all sites' locale to UK:

```
$LocaleId = 2057 # UK
$TimeZoneId = 2 # London
$credentials = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite -Credentials $credentials
$sites=Get-PnPTenantSite
foreach($site in $sites){
Connect-PnPOnline $site.Url -Credentials $credentials
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes RegionalSettings,RegionalSettings.TimeZones
$timeZone = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZones | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $TimeZoneId}
$web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId = $LocaleId
$web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone = $timeZone
$web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
}
```

The script did the job for SP sites, but all OneDrive sites came as "Access Denied" because of unique permissions.

So I was thinking to add the account running the script as secondary admin to OneDrive sites, run the above script and remove the account at the end of the script and leave the original permissions to sites.

Adding something as:

```
#Store 2nd Admin account into a variable
$adminAcctToAdd = "sharepoint.admin@company.com"

#Add 2nd Site Collection admin
Set-SPOUser -Site $url.PersonalUrl -LoginName $adminAcctToAdd -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
```

Run the above locale change script and at the end remove the secondary admin:

```
Set-SPOUser -Site $url.PersonalUrl -LoginName $adminAcctToRemove -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $false
```

Any help how to bolt that together?

Much appreciated! Best!

Answer (score 0):

You could run the below script for all onedrive sites:

```
#Store  Admin account into a variable
$adminAcctToAdd = "sharepoint.admin@company.com"
#Get OneDrive sites
$sites=Get-PnPTenantSite -IncludeOneDriveSites -Filter "Url -like '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'"
foreach($site in $sites){
    #Add Admin account as an additional site collection adminstrator
    Set-PnPTenantSite $site.url -Owners $adminAcctToAdd
    
    Connect-PnPOnline $site.Url -Credentials $credentials
    $web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes RegionalSettings,RegionalSettings.TimeZones
    $timeZone = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZones | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $TimeZoneId}
    $web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId = $LocaleId
    $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone = $timeZone
    $web.Update()
    Invoke-PnPQuery
    
    #Remove Admin account from site colletion administrators
    Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin -Owners $adminAcctToAdd
}
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Han_MSFT, 
Would you confirm - shall I add your script to the script in the beginning (my one)?
If so - $sites will be involved twice - $sites=Get-PnPTenantSite for SPO sites and $sites=Get-PnPWeb for OneDrive sites in the same script.

Also my account is SP admin so for the normal SP sites I do not need to add my account as secondary owner, but it will be necessary for private Teams channel sites and OD.

So how to manage not removing my account as a site admin on SPO sites, but add to OneDrive and MS Teams private channels SP sites?

Many thanks!